Is there a chance I could stay in Germany permanently if I got a job at a cafe or as a bartender?
I have a bachelor's degree but it's not in a field that is in high demand, and I don't have any experience in the service industry. I've known quite a few people who barely speak a word of German but can somehow stay in Berlin for long periods of time and I've heard that quite a few bars and cafes in Berlin don't require people to speak German, but I'm enthusiastically learning the language. So, could I theoretically travel to Berlin and hand in my CV to various cafes and bars? Or would most places rather not deal with that?

What's your concern / question exactly? Immigration, job market? Language is an issue but if you are an EU citizen, you don't need to worry about immigration and might find a job. You will however find that the housing market is very tight. That's why you might find a job and grow tired of it as not many people want to put up permanently with a pay that's not that high relative to the cost of living. Or if they do, they prefer seasonal jobs that offer even bare bones accommodation instead of living alone in the city.

My concern was that I am not a citizen of the EU. Im from the US

Assuming that "I'm from the US" means you are a citizen of the US, I edited your question's tags to include "us-citizens" and "germany." If you are not a US citizen (perhaps you are instead a citizen of another country living in the US with a US visa or green card), these new tags would be inappropriate, and should be removed.

Are those people you know who barely speak a word of German possibly EU or dual citizens or perhaps married to one? In your situation, immigration is going to be an even bigger issue than finding a job as a non-German speaker, potential employers are unlikely to want the hassle of sponsoring a residence permit, if that is even possible. If you are young, a work-holiday programme or a student visa might be an option for a few years but that won't last forever.


could I theoretically travel to Berlin and hand in my CV to various cafes and bars?

Leaving aside the issue of needing a visa that allows you to work in Germany, the simple answer to your question is Yes. You can legally search for work as a visitor.
However, as others have commented, just finding vacant unskilled bar work/hospitality jobs is likely the easy part of this scenario. Actually living and working in a city where your earnings are low relative to the cost of living, finding accommodation you can afford/want to live in is difficult, you work unsociable hours, and don’t have a reasonable grasp of the language (say B1 level), is probably not that simple or enjoyable.

If you have enough money to risk it, you can try. Don't do it if the flight makes a hole in your budget.

US citizens are in a very privileged position regarding German immigration law. You can enter without a visa, you can search for a job without a visa, and you can apply for a work permit from within Germany.
A small business like a cafe or restaurant may be reluctant to hire someone who does not yet have a work permit because of the administrative overhead. You should be open when you talk to them.
The relatively easy ways for getting a work permit is for skilled workers, who are defined as earning a good salary. The restaurant business is paid notoriously bad.
Finding affordable housing in Berlin is difficult.

